# How Can I change the color of the "google-icons for my website

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I have a problem.
Please can anyone help me out? I am creating a clone of flipkart.com ( an Ecom website).
I need some icons of the same color as which are on their website. I found some on google fonts, but only have two color variations ( Black & white).
I need same icon in yellow color can anyone help me out through this.

Google fonts link--- https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=suitcase

```
<span class="material-icons-outlined">
```

work_outline

work_outline br
codepoint
e943

Comment: download it in svg format and change colors using css

Answer (score 1):

Apply styles with `css`. Does this work?

```css
html, body {height: 100%}
body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  fill: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M14 6V4h-4v2h4zM4 8v11h16V8H4zm16-2c1.11 0 2 .89 2 2v11c0 1.11-.89 2-2 2H4c-1.11 0-2-.89-2-2l.01-11c0-1.11.88-2 1.99-2h4V4c0-1.11.89-2 2-2h4c1.11 0 2 .89 2 2v2h4z"/></svg>
```

Comment: @RiadRekab What isn't working?

Comment: The css is not working when you use <span>  but I guess your code is  not compatible for span

Comment: @RiadRekab the code is for ```svg``` elements. If you are looking for an answer, make sure to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

download it as a .svg file and put it in your code. Use `fill: red;` to make it the color you want it to be.

`<img src="image.svg" alt="image" fill="red">`

This should work :)

Comment: Thanks for help,  but it is not working. I tried it in both HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the icon as .SVG from [Material Icons page](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material%20Icons)
2. Open the downloaded .svg image in a text editor
3. Scroll a bit to the right and find `fill="#000000"` (or `fill="#FFFFFF"` for white icon)
4. Change that HEX color to your desired one (check out [colorpicker.me](https://colorpicker.me/))

   - e.g. `fill="#FFFF00"` for yellow
5. Save, and embed the image to your website with `<img src="icon.svg">`